# "Template is missing" when rendering Liquid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, template-engine, liquid

I'm trying to render a liquid template that is stored in the database.

Here is my 'show' action in the controller:

```
  def show
    @organization = Organization.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
    @template = Liquid::Template.parse(Template.find(@organization.current_template).body)
    @page = @organization.pages.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render @template.render('page' => @page), :template => false}
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end
```

However, when I visit the page, I get a "Template is Missing" exception with the following error (note that "testing testing" is the body attribute of the page object, which is currently the only thing being rendered in the template):

```
Missing template /testing testing with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}.
Searched in: * "/Users/ashercohen/Documents/Rails/Vocalem-Rails/app/views" 
* "/Users/ashercohen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.1/app/views"
* "/Users/ashercohen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

Why is it trying to find another template, when I've specifically pass the `:template => false` argument? Is there something I'm missing here? I'm trying to bypass using any template files, as it seems like they shouldn't be needed here (though am not strongly opposed if I am wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Because render almost always takes a filename, while `@template.render('page' => @page)` contains the plain html. You should invoke render like this:

```
render :text => @template.render('page' => @page), :content_type => :html
```

Comment: For rails version `>= 4.1` `text` should be replaced with `plain`: `render plain: @template.render('page' => @page), content_type: :html`